# Remove: Change Order New

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, contenttype

I Have a Sharepoint Envirioment with several content types. I have in my context menu a button for changing the contenttype order. How can i disable this button.

I want to remove this button from the context menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the option in the documentlibrary: allow modifying content type